# Uncaught Exception: object does not have any method getInsatnce -DojoMobile

Tags: dojo

I am using dojo version 10 to load an external view on button click. I tried including dojo/Deferred in require, still it's throwing the same error. What can be possibly wrong?

The error I am getting in LogCat-

> Uncaught exception:object has no method'getInstance' at compiled code.

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="dojox/mobile/deviceTheme.js"
        data-dojo-config="mblThemeFiles: ['base','Button']"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
   require([
      "dojox/mobile/parser",
       "dijit/registry",
       "dojox/mobile/ViewController",
    "dojox/mobile/Heading",
       "dojox/mobile",
       "dojox/mobile/Button",
       "dojox/mobile/View",
       "dojo/Deferred"
     
      
   ], function(registry, ViewController){
       var vc = ViewController.getInstance();
       onBtn1Clicked = function(e){
           // the external view is loaded under the "container" view.
           vc.openExternalView({
            url:"external.html",
            transition:"slide"
        }, registry.byId("container").containerNode);
    };
});
  
   </script>
```

```html
  <div id="home" data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/View">
    <h1 data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/Heading">Home</h1>
    <button data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/Button" id="btn1" style="margin:5px;"
            data-dojo-props='onClick:onBtn1Clicked'>Load external view</button>
    </div>
    <div id="container" data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/View">
    <!-- An external view is loaded here when clicking the button above -->
     </div>
```

HI4g.png

Comment: Thanks not necessary in questions, use voting & accepting

Answer (score 0):

your arguments to the callback in the `require()` do not match.
There should be one-to-one mapping between the modules and callback arguments.

```
       require([
           "dojox/mobile/parser",
            "dijit/registry",
            "dojox/mobile/ViewController",
            "dojox/mobile/Heading",
            "dojox/mobile",
            "dojox/mobile/Button",
            "dojox/mobile/View",
            "dojo/Deferred"

           /* Arguments should match the module. parser was missing as the first argument */
        ], function( parser, registry, ViewController){
              // rest of your code here.

         }, registry.byId("container").containerNode);
```